# How can I check only one check box at a time instead of all in a list of checkboxes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of chat room channels for people to talk i.e there is a `lifestyle channel`, `shopping channel`, `pets channel` etc.

I am now trying to categorise each channel to make it easier for the user to find what they want. In order to do so, on creation of a chatroom channel I need the user to select which category the channel they are creating best fits into. A bit like YouTube does when you upload a video.

So far I have created a separate component which is a list of checkboxes with the different categories the user can put their channel into:

```
import React from 'react';

const options = [
  { label: "Lifestyle", value: "lifestyle"},
  { label: "Area", value: "area" },
  { label: "Random", value: "random" },
  { label: "Comedy", value: "comedy" },
  { label: "Entertainment", value: "entertainment" }
];
const ChannelCategory = (props) => {
return  (
  <div>
    {props.title}
    <ul>
    {options.map((option) => (
     <li key={props.key}>
       <label>
       {option.label}
       <input
         className={props.className}
         name="test"
         checked={props.checked}
         onChange={() => props.onChange(option.value)}
         type="checkbox"
       />
       </label>
     </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
  </div>
)
};
export default ChannelCategory;
```

I am using the above component on the page below, I would like that when the user selects just ONE of the options only ONE input box is checked, however at the moment when I click ONE input box for instance `lifestyle` they ALLLL get checked and for every single channel too:( Any ideas why?

```
 const [checked, setCheckBoxChecked] = useState(false);
[...]
  const onAddCategory = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    if (value === "lifestyle") {
      setCheckBoxChecked(checked => !checked); 
    }
    if (value === "area") {
      setCheckBoxChecked(checked => !checked); 
    }
    if (value === "random") {
      setCheckBoxChecked(checked => !checked); 
    }
    if (value === "comedy") {
      setCheckBoxChecked(checked => !checked); 
    }
  };

[...]
  const options = [
    { label: "Lifestyle", value: "lifestyle"},
    { label: "Area", value: "area" },
    { label: "Random", value: "random" },
    { label: "Comedy", value: "comedy" },
    { label: "Entertainment", value: "entertainment" }
  ];

  return (
    <form noValidate autoComplete='off' onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <Card style={styles.card}>
        <CardContent>
          <Box padding={3}>
            <FormLegend title={`${formTitle} (${channels.length})`} description={formDescription} />
            <Box marginTop={3} width='50%'>
              <Grid container direction='column' justify='flex-start' alignItems='stretch' spacing={1}>
                {channels.map(channel => {
                  return (
                  <Grid key={channel.key} item style={styles.gridItem} justify="space-between">
                    <ChannelListItem
                      channel={channel}
                      isSaving={isSaving}
                      onDeleteChannelClick={onDeleteChannelClick}
                      key={channel.Key}
                      onFormControlChange={onFormControlChange} 
                      onUndoChannelClick={onUndoChannelClick}
                    />
                    <ChannelCategory
                      key={channel.key}
                      options={options}
                      onChange={value => onAddCategory(value)}
                      title="Add your chatroom to a category so that users can find it easily"
                      checked={checked}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  )
                })}
          [...]
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>

    </form>
  );
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the method `onAddCategory` that you use in the prop onChange aswell as the rest of the code involving the variable `checked`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTihanyi hi done, I updated the code. I had the wrong name for the method. Should be right now

Comment: use a radio button !

Answer (score 3):

Instead of storing true or false inside the checked variable, you should store the value inside of checked. Like this:

```
const onChangeAttribute = (value) => {
  console.log(value);
  setCheckBoxChecked(value);
};
```

And now while rendering the checkbox you should check if checked is equal to the name of that checkbox like this:

```
<input
     className={props.className}
     name={option.value}
     checked={props.checked === option.value}
     onChange={() => props.onChange(option.value)}
     type="checkbox"
/>
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: This works, thank you so much!!  People are saying I should use a radio button though, do you agree?

Comment: @AngelaInniss yeah radio button can work as well but they are best suited for situations where we want the user to select only one input out of all but in your case they can be more than one so checkboxes are better choice for this very situation

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to store all checked boxes and in your `ChannelCategory` check if the current value exists in the checked array then set checked to true for that checkbox. If you want to select only one category use radio buttons

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const options = [
  { label: "Lifestyle", value: "lifestyle" },
  { label: "Area", value: "area" },
  { label: "Random", value: "random" },
  { label: "Comedy", value: "comedy" },
  { label: "Entertainment", value: "entertainment" }
];

const ChannelCategory = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.title}
      <ul>
        {props.options.map(option => (
          <li key={props.key}>
            <label>
              {option.label}
              <input
                className={props.className}
                name={option.value}
                checked={props.checked.includes(option.value)}
                onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.checked, option.value)}
                type="checkbox"
              />
            </label>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [checked, setCheckBoxChecked] = useState([]);

  const onAddCategory = (isChecked, value) => {
    const temp = [...checked];

    if (isChecked) {
      temp.push(value);
      setCheckBoxChecked(temp);

      return;
    }

    setCheckBoxChecked(temp.filter(item => item !== value));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChannelCategory
        key={"channel.key"}
        options={options}
        onChange={onAddCategory}
        title="Add your chatroom to a category so that users can find it easily"
        checked={checked}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

[Radio buttons example](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-bush-cj8rq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thank you so , if i only want to select one option use a radio button like in your code sandbox ok got it! If i want to select multiple I should use your code above right?